# Do modern aircraft still have PCMCIA?

Tags: aircraft-performance, engine

Do modern aircraft still have PCMCIA for engine monitoring?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if floppy disk is still in use.

Comment: I didn't know they used PCMCIA. I thought they used more specialised hardware.

Comment: @ManuH According to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviationmaintenance/comments/92qmbm/what_does_a_pcmcia_card_do_in_airbus/) Airbus, Boeing, and Embraer use (or used) them: _"It’s a memory card that goes into the FDIMU (Flight Data Interface and Management Unit) and records various flight parameters, engine performance data, interfaces with the ACMS (Aircraft Condition Monitoring System), ACARS and various other computers on the plane."_

Comment: My plane uses a micro SD card to download engine performance data.  Other boxes in my plane use a USB stick. The plane is not modern (46 years old) but the avionics are modern and engine monitoring system are new.

Comment: Without a clear definition of "modern aircraft", this question is too broad. Many airplanes, even older aircraft that have been retrofitted with newer electronics, won't use PCMCIA, because newer, improved I/O interfaces are available. On the other hand, surely there are _some_ aircraft flying today that are essentially "modern" as compared to the early days of aviation, and which still have PCMCIA interfaces. Please be more specific as to what you consider "modern". (That said, I do doubt that a clean sheet 21st century design would be using PCMCIA.)